# What are the requisites for RAM in a MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, memory

I've just purchased my MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) *(it's not the retina model where RAM is fixed)* and I'm considering more RAM. On the system information app, I found this info.

```
BANK 0/DIMM0: 2GB DDR3 1600 MHz OK
BANK 1/DIMM0: 2GB DDR3 1600 MHz OK
```

Will any RAM, DDR3, 1600MHz work or does the MacBbook have some other requirement to be compatible that isn't listed above?

Comment: Is this a retina or non-retina model? On non-retina, any 1600 MHz DDR3 SODIMM will work. If it's retina, the RAM is soldered to the board and cannot be replaced.

Comment: My shopping advice for upgrading memory in Macintosh computers is to buy from a place that specializes in Macintosh. I've bought RAM which should have been fine spec-wise, but didn't work. When I ordered from a Macintosh specialist (OWC) RAM with the same specs worked fine.

Comment: It's non-retina. I've already searched in OWC, but in my country I can't find a store that sales their products.
Do you think that this model should work?
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820233382

Comment: I believe there are CAS timing recommendations, but can't find a good "official" link from Apple, but I implicitly trust [RamJet's description of RAM needs](http://ramjet.com/macbook.asp#BlackBezel) for every Mac that's been made. If no one digs up an answer, that might be a good place to check for requirements.

Comment: @WarrenPena Thanks for the flags and for working to improve the question.

Comment: Just one more question, I found that the maximum memory that it supports it's 8GB. Now, that would be on each slot (8+8 = 16GB) or 8 total  (4+4 = 8GB)?
(http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1270)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any 1600 MHz DDR3 SODIMM will work.  You do not need to buy one from OWC or any Mac specialty shop.

Comment: One more question, I found that the maximum memory that it supports it's 8GB. Now, that would be on each slot (8+8 = 16GB) or 8 total (4+4 = 8GB)?